# How to centre align floating DIVs within a parent DIV?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where I have three divs within a parent div which need to be center aligned. I do not understand why the center alignment of the text isn't doing it's usual magic?

I have recreated the issue here [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1rLs9fx/)

```
<div class="container_alt">

    <div class="pricing_options_col">

        <div class="pck1">pck1</div>

        <div class="pck2">pck2</div>

        <div class="pck3">pck3</div>

    </div>

</div> 

.container_alt{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.pricing_options{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;  
    display:inline-block;
}

.pricing_options_col{
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px 0;
    display:inline-block;
}


.pck1{
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;    
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;          
}

.pck2{
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    z-index: 999999;    
}

.pck3{
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: pink; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;                  
}
```

Comment: setting `float:left` tells the div to move as far left as it can. this is contrary to your desire to center them. do they need to be floated left, or do they just need to be side-by-side?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow they will need to be sat side by side but in center of the parent Div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.pck1`, `pck2` and `pck3`, remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block`.

Floating an element is used to move it all the way to one side or the other (which obviously does the opposite of cetering). Preventing the "stacking" is a by-product of that, but there are other ways to keep elements from stacking. By default, divs have `display:block`, which means they'll each display on their own line ("stacking"). By changing it to `display:inline-block`, they display in-line.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xn5n5pnL/).

Comment: Your suggestion re change `float: left;` into `display-inline-block;` helped me lot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

remove `float: left;` from the css for .pck1 .pck2 .pck3

**update**: i guess this is what you are looking for:

```
.pricing_options_col{
    width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Removing the floats stacks them on top of each other.

Comment: @stacking this should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is because your `parent` and `child` both holds the `width` of `100%`

```
.pricing_options_col{
    width: 100%; <-- Remove
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/x1rLs9fx/1/)